# How to make asynchronous tasks have lower priority in Java 8?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, java-8

I have a service that handles the main entity, retrieves the first sub-entity associated with the main entity, then returns both. It also sets off a set of completable `Future` chains to go out & retrieve any additional entities. Currently, I just take a prebuilt set of retrieval tasks, wrap a `Future` async around them, then set it off with a `CachedThreadPool`. This is fine, but when 50+ users hit the server the primary task (of retrieving the main entity & the first sub-entity) is dramatically slowed by all of the async threads running.

I want to know if there is a way to make the asynchronous calls to run on a lower priority in order to make sure the primary call is handled quickly.

```
  public CompletableFuture buildFutureTasks(P primaryEntity, List<List<S>> entityGroups)
  {
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    CompletableFuture<Void> future = null;
    for (List<S> entityGroup : entityGroups)
    {
      if (future == null || future.isDone())
      {
        future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() ->
            retrieveSubEntitiesForEntity(primaryEntity, entityGroup), pool);
      }
      else
      {
        future.thenRunAsync(() ->
            retrieveSubEntitiesForEntities(primaryEntity, entityGroup), pool);
      }
    }
    return future;
  }
```

This is the fastest I've been able to make this run with 50+ users but it still dramatically slows down the more users I add.

Comment: My guess is that if this slows down dramatically at 50 users then you have a problem that's not related to thread priority.

Comment: Can you specify better from which source you "retrieve any additional entities". Generally speaking a non-blocking framework may be helpful in reducing the overhead of many running threads if the data-fetching client allows it. See Akka and Netty for reference.

Comment: Consider using a maximumPoolSize to reduce the parallel working threads.

Comment: You are not only using an unbounded thread pool executor that may create an arbitrary number of threads, you are also creating a new one in each method invocation, never shutting it down. This means these excess threads hang around for a minute after completing their work, before automatic clean up may occur. Besides that—what’s the point of creating a new thread for each sub entity when you are chaining them in a way that they can’t run at the same time anyway?

Comment: @markspace Specifically, the significant decrease is when I'm running jMeter, with a number of 50 users & a loop a 3 I see my response time go from 400-600ms to 1.4-2s overhead time. This is with hitting a separate service that is responding with a static payload.

Comment: @tkruse, It's a parent-child relationship with sets of data. For example, related products, like the options you see when you select an amazon's item it shows you a set of related products. In this, it would be something like additional sets of related products.

Comment: @Holger, The method is called once per user so at most they have 1 background task running to retrieve the sub-entities, in the order set. Both you & St.Antario bring up a good point about the pool being created each call however & I shall move that to the component level.

Comment: No, you are potentially creating one thread for *each* element of the `entityGroups`, as each of these stages may get submitted to the executor, at a point when the submitting worker thread is not free to pick it up. Using the same executor does not imply using the same thread. So the maximum number of threads is the product of the list size and the number of users calling this method within one minute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are most likely to know already, there is a method `Thread::setPriority`. But as to the `JavaDoc`

> Every thread has a priority. Threads with higher priority are executed
>   in preference to threads with lower priority.

So you can just provide a `ThreadFactory` when creating your cached  `ExecutorService`.
The actual thread scheduling details is VM-implementation specific so you cannot really rely on this. I would consider using fixedThreadPool instead

But I'm not sure that the actual problem is about thread scheduling and priority. First of all, cached thread pool can (as to the documentation)

> Creates a thread pool that creates ***new threads as needed***, but will
>   reuse previously constructed threads when they are available.

In case of 50+ users which can call `buildFutureTasks` you cannot really control the number of threads created.

1. I would consider using `fixedThreadPool` so you can control if don't really need `SynchronousQueue` which is the underlying of cached thread pools.
2. Consider using the same `ThreadPool` for all the task and not create it inside the method `buildFutureTasks` every time it is called.

Comment: That makes sense to me. Let me ask, how much percent of threads should I make the background async task pool thread at if you had any particular opinion on that?

Comment: @user1760412 It depends on the tasks. If your tasks are computations that are CPU-intensive then there is no reason to create more than `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()`. But if the tasks for example submit some jobs on a remote host and just wait for the result... you may well create 3 x `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` or more pool size.